# Get altitude over WGS84 ellipsoid from GPS tracking app

Tags: gps, kml, software-recommendations, tracking

I have been using multiple GPS tracking apps for sailing in my iPhone, such as [iSailor](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/w%C3%A4rtsil%C3%A4-isailor/id398456162), whose output is a KML file that looks like

```
            ...        
            <when>2023-08-16T09:12:51Z</when>
            <gx:coord>-3.021280436 47.421095956 0.0</gx:coord>
            <when>2023-08-16T09:12:52Z</when>
            <gx:coord>-3.021279479 47.421099017 0.0</gx:coord>
           ...
```

As you can see, the third column, that is supposed to represent the altitude over the WGS84 ellipsoid, is identically equal to zero.

In fact, I have never found a tracking app that gives me the altitude.

Is this an app or a phone issue?

Do you know an app that gives the altitude?

Comment: One would expect that altitude at the sea level would be 0.

Comment: No, that is the altitude with respect to the WGS84 ellipsoid.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question belongs on Software Recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

It is unlikely that the WGS84 ellipsoid heights would be identical to an orthometric or tidal vertical datum height for your area of interest (but that is possible).

Here in the USA we have access to [vDatum](https://vdatum.noaa.gov/docs/datums.html#wgs84) to convert between vertical datums.  In my area of NW Washington State WGS84 is about 18m below the North American Vertical Datum of 1988 (NAVD88). NAVD88 is an orthometric height based on equipotential gravity and the national elevation standard for the USA, Canada, and Mexico.

I can confirm that my iPhone Compass app is not returning heights in WGS84 using a LiDAR derived NAVD88 surface models and vDatum conversions.  In fact, the iPhone compass app is reading 4.8 meters over NAVD88.  After trying all the likely vertical datum conversions I cannot duplicate the iPhone elevation values.

I see from online that some suggest the iPhone is using a barometric altimeter for iPhone sold after 2016.  It is unclear how that elevation would be calibrated for weather change.  There is a storm brewing outside currently so the low barometric pressure could explain altimeter theory and why my iPhone is giving an elevation close but above NAVD88.  I will report back when the weather changes.

As for your specific question you will have to contact the app creators to see what values are being expressed in your app. Only the coders know what is being recorded there.  It stands to reason that since it is a sailing app the app is returning a default of 0 since most people do not care or know about vertical datums. It is unlikely that your app is doing vertical datum shifts as those conversion files require GBs of data.

If you would like to test vertical datum differences outside of the USA territorial waters consider using [Proj](https://proj.org/en/9.2/operations/transformations/vgridshift.html).

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, but it does not really answer my question, which is, plainly: you know an app that gives the altitude above the WGS 84 Ellipsoid?

Comment: Ah, then I am voting to close as this question belongs on another SE site...but you do have the information to figure that one out yourself now.  FYI, after looking at a few GNSS apps for iPhone  I see that they are returning barometric heights despite the app description in the app store.